# update datetime field by making values utc sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I originally inserting my data fields using US east coast time 'local server time' and now its causing me problems interacting with other applications that use utc time. Being that the time is in a datetime field, is their any way in sql server to update all records to utc time which is 4 hours ahead of current vales?

Comment: Are _all_ times 4 hours from UTC, or are some DST and some not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could do this:

```
UPDATE table SET field = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, field)
```